# Smoothness of locus of triples $(B_1,B_2,i)$ in Nakajima's notes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, commuting-variety

In section 1.4 of Nakajima's notes on Lectures on Hilbert Schemes, it is mentioned that $(\mathbb A^2)^{[n]}$ is identified with the space of triples $\{(B_1,B_2,i)\}/GL_n$. Here $B_1,B_2$ are $n\times n$ commuting matrices in $M_n(\mathbb C)$ and $i\in \mathbb C^n$ is a vector such that the vectors $\{B_1^aB_2^bi\mid a,b\geq0\}$ span all of $\mathbb C^n$. Consider the locus of such triples $(B_1,B_2,i)\in M_n(\mathbb C)\times M_n(\mathbb C)\times \mathbb C^n$. It is clear that this is a locally closed subscheme. Is this space, with the reduced scheme structure, smooth? If yes, is there an easy way to see this?

If we drop the vector $i$, then it seems that it is a conjecture of Artin and Hochster that the ideal $I$ in the ring $R=k[X_{ij},Y_{ij}]$ generated by the entries of the matrix $XY-YX$ is such that $R/I$ CM. This ideal is known to be irreducible due to Richardson (Commuting varieties of semisimple Lie algebras and algebraic groups. Compositio Math. 38 (1979), no. 3, 311–327).

Comment: Yes, that locus is smooth by Fogarty's proof of smoothness of the Hilbert scheme.  One proof of Fogarty's Theorem uses the Hilbert-Burch-Schaps Theorem (on the other hand, you might feel that theorem is no easier that Fogarty's Theorem).

Comment: Let me add some details: your triple makes $\mathbb{C}^n$ a module over $\mathbb{C}[t_1,t_2]$ together with a surjective module homomorphism $i$ from $\mathbb{C}[t_1,t_2]$ sending each $t_1^{a_1}t_2^{a_2}$ to $B_1^{a_1}B_2^{a_2}i$.  By the Hilbert Syzygy Theorem, the kernel of this surjection is itself the cokernel of an injective homomorphism of modules, $j:\mathbb{C}[t_1,t_2]^{\oplus r} \to \mathbb{C}[t_1,t_2]^{\oplus(r+1)}$.  This is just an $(r+1)\times r$ matrix, and the kernel of $i$ is the ideal of $r\times r$ minors.  Deformations of the triple come from deformations of the matrix $j$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was trying to fill in some details for my understanding. However, I am confused. If we denote the locus of triples $(B_1,B_2,i)\subset M_n(\mathbb C)\times M_n(\mathbb C)\times \mathbb C^n$ by $T$, then our aim is to show that $T$ is smooth. It seems to me that you are giving a map from some smooth space of matrices (ones determined by $j$) to $T$. Let us call this space of matrices $S$. It is not clear to me what $S$ is?

Comment: A locally finitely presented scheme is smooth if and only if it is formally smooth.  The proof via Hilbert-Burch-Schaps shows that the scheme is the target of a surjective morphism that is formally smooth with formally smooth domain.  Thus the target scheme is also formally smooth.